# R: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Tags: r

How to fix this incomprehensible issue? I created a df for plotting. This worked with the observation group A. But it stopped working after I replaced (with `filter` function) observation group A with the observation group B. Another addition was, that I added `na.omit` function to the df code.

This is the code for plotting, that produces the error `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1`

```
ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(data = df, x = name, y = value, effsize.type = "partial_eta", 
                            mean.ci = TRUE, pairwise.comparisons = TRUE, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni", 
                            bf.message = FALSE, title = "Title of Graph",
                            xlab = "X-axis label", ylab = "Y-axis label")
```

But the df's columns have equal number of rows, both have 81.

Here's the df I used:

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", 
"MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", 
"START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", 
"END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", 
"MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", 
"START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", 
"END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", 
"MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END", "START", "MIDDLE", "END"), value = c(5.20175438596491, 
5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 
5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 
5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 
5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 
5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 
5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 
5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 
5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 
5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 
5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 
5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 
5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 
5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 
5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 
5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 
5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 
5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 
5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 
5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 
5.62068965517241, 5.20175438596491, 5.62745098039216, 5.62068965517241
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-81L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `pairwise.comparison` to FALSE.

```
ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(data = df, x = name, y = value, effsize.type = "partial_eta", 
                            mean.ci = TRUE, pairwise.comparisons = FALSE, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni", 
                            bf.message = FALSE, title = "Title of Graph",
                            xlab = "X-axis label", ylab = "Y-axis label")
```

[image]